# Convert an image with black background to a black and white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Is there a way to convert an image with a bleck background to a bleck and white so that I can use it as a mask in Cycles?
Here's the idea - From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

I'm creating this Earth scene from "blenderguru.com" (link below) howeever, the clouds in Cycles are not visible enough and part of the clouds is fully transparent -

Internal - 
[image]

Cycles - 
[image]

Internal material -

[image]

Cycles material -

[image]

I don't know what it does in the Internal, but I expect the same result in Cycles. If anyone can explain to me why do clowds are less visible in Cycles?

Earth tutorial - http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-earth/

Comment: By the way, I used the same clouds texture for the Fac of the Mix Shader.

Comment: have you tried using index of object as a mask ?

Comment: not sure what you need, but you can add a color ramp to your cloud mask image (mix fac) to control cloud's transparency

Comment: I did thought of that, but isn't there a way to just isolate/remove the clowds from the mask, 'cause the color ramp wouldn't do it perfect. I haven tried index for an image. I'll see how it works.

Comment: do you need your cloud's shapes or sphere's shape as mask?

Comment: Just the image - http://www.pasteall.org/pic/84570
The part with the clouds would be pure white so that I can just use it as a mask to hide the black part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to create a mask from BW image you can use this nodes :

[image]

you can change the threshold for different results

Comment: color ramp (constant) can give easier/more visual control.

Comment: You're right (I should spend more time on ramping). In the compositor when the ColorRamp is switched to "Constant" it separates it perfectly. Thanks for the answer.